# Oracle form builder not getting values from server

Tags: sql, oracle, platform-builder

I am logged into a sql server. when i insert values via SQL*Plus server, they are not registered by Form builder, but when i insert them using form builder, they do appear when i search for them on SQL*Plus...

what is going on and how do i get form builder to register the values entered in SQL*Plus??

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.... i wan't using commit in sql plus :D